# System Cron not working

Tags: ui

I am using Joomla30 as the CMS on a hosted website, so I am unable to access the terminal.  I have instead tried your suggested alternative of easycron using a URL to start cron.php (I have confirmed that the url is correct for that file).  I have used the POST method and inserted the required parameters.  This doesn't work and I get a message "Internal Server Error".  The process took 1.5 seconds to return, so it can't be the maximum time limit.
The civicrm version is 5.20.0
The service provider provides CWP as the control panel, and their offering on cron is hopeless.
Please can you help me?
Regards,

Bill

Answer (score 1):

Use the log viewer extension (you can install it from the extensions tab if the permissions are setup right, or see here: https://civicrm.org/extensions/civicrm-log-viewer).

It should show you what the error is and point you to what needs fixing.

The fact that it went for the 1.5 seconds suggests it's an issue with a specific one of your jobs, so you could go to your list of system jobs (Administer -> System Settings -> Scheduled Jobs) and review the logs of those that are running. Looking at the dates of when they were last run might provide some other clues. You can also manually run them to see if that provides additional clues.

If you're lucky, perhaps you just have a job enabled that shouldn't be enabled.

If you're not lucky, you might have a system configuration problem (e.g. php version, or required php module missing, etc.).